# Trench Real Analysis real numbers problem

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $S$ and $T$ be non-empty sets of real numbers such that every real number is in $S$ or $T$ and if $s\in S$ and $t \in T$, then $s \lt t$. Prove that there is a unique real number $B$ such that every real number less than $B$ is in $S$ and every real number greater than $B$ is in $T$.

How can I prove this? There is some mention of Dedekind cuts.

Comment: First impulse: Show that $\sup S=\inf T$ and then take $B$ to be their common value.

Comment: Intuitively that was the first thing that came to mind but how can I show that rigorously?Maybe using epsilon characterization of infimum and supremum.

Answer (score 3):

Given any element $t\in T$, it is an upper bound for $S$.  $S$ must have a least upper bound, which is the $b$ you seek.  By a similar argument $T$ must have a greatest lower bound $c$.  If $c \lt b$, there must be an element of $T$ less than some element of $S$.  If $c \gt b$ the numbers between $b$ and $c$ cannot belong to either $S$ or $T$, so $c=b$. Now every number less than $b$ must be in $S$ and every number greater must be in $T$.  $b$ can go in either one.